# Why can't I execute a SQL function using the .net Entity Framework?

Tags: .net, sql, entity-framework

I have written the following code in my .net project.  I've never used the Entity Framework before, and this is the very first thing I want to do: execute a function and save the result

```
using System.Data.Objects;

MyEntities entities = new MyEntities

var result0 = entities.CreateQuery<string>("SELECT XXX FROM Fn_Org_GetXXX('XXXX',2012);").first();

var result1 = entities.ExecuteFunction("fn_org_getXXX", new ObjectParameter[]
    {
        new ObjectParameter("location","XXXX"),
        new ObjectParameter("fiscalyear",2012)
    });
```

Both lines of code throw exception indicating that the function doesn't exist. However, when I run the aforementioned code in SQL Server Management Studio, it works fine. I am logging in to the SQL server using the same credentials.

The error for result0 says:

> 'Fn_Org_GetXXX' cannot be resolved into a valid type or function.

The error for result1 says:

> The FunctionImport 'fn_org_getXXX' could not be found in the
>   container 'MyEntities'.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think SQL User Defined Functions is supported in Entity Framework right now. Here is a [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/05/14/sneak-preview-model-defined-functions.aspx) that you can define it  in edmx schema .

There are some updates from [June 2011 CTP](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/06/30/walkthrough-table-valued-functions-june-ctp.aspx), but I don't think it's released yet.

Comment: So, what about my first line of code that just passes in a sql command as a line of text?  Any idea why that doesn't worK?` var result0 = entities.CreateQuery<string>("SELECT XXX FROM Fn_Org_GetXXX('XXXX',2012);").first();`

Answer (score -1):

Functions need the schema name in their calling convention. So if your function is created on the dbo schema you would call it as `dbo.fn_org_getXXX`

Comment: When qualify the schema name, I get this exception: `The container 'dbo' specified for the FunctionImport could not be found in the current workspace.`